# Message sent to Android Wear gets lost

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to send some strings to the my Wear from my Phone using MessageAPI. The message however fails to reach the Wear around 75% of the time. This is the problem, its behaviour is totally at least to me, unpredictable. The factors that determine whether the Message reaches or not are unknown. I have read previous answers and have tried checking whether the watch and phone are connected before sending the message, but this hasn't worked either. Both are clearly connected, but still the message fails to reach. Below is the code from my Phone app:

```
    private static void sendMessage(final String path, final String duration, final String type, final String name, final String startingTime,final Context context) {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Bundle inBundle = new Bundle();
            inBundle.putString("duration", duration);
            inBundle.putString("type", type); // will be failed
            inBundle.putString("name", name); // will be failed
            inBundle.putString("Starting Time", startingTime);
            inBundle.putBoolean("Stop", false);

            // From Bundle to bytes
            byte[] inBytes = bundleToBytes(inBundle);

            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mGoogleApiClient ).await();

            for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), path, inBytes ).await();


                Log.i("Node:",nodes.getNodes().toString());
            }

            Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, new NodeApi.NodeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
                    Log.i("Node:","Ab connected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {

                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Below is my Android Wear's code for Message reception:

```
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    if( messageEvent.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase( START_ACTIVITY ) ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        startActivity( intent );

        Bundle outBundle = jsonStringToBundle(new String(messageEvent.getData()));

        String duration = outBundle.getString("duration");
        stop=outBundle.getBoolean("Stop");
        String type = outBundle.getString("type");
        String name = outBundle.getString("name");
        String startingTime= outBundle.getString("Starting Time");

        Bundle b= new Bundle();
        b.putInt("duration", Integer.parseInt(duration));
        b.putString("Starting Time",startingTime);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),duration + " : " + startingTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        if(!stop) {
            AcquisitionStatus=true;
            Intent sensorServ = new Intent(MyService.this, SensorService.class);
            sensorServ.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            sensorServ.putExtras(b);
            startService(sensorServ);

        }
        else {
            AcquisitionStatus = false;
           // setAcquisitionStatus(false);
        }

    }
    else if (  messageEvent.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase("TestPath") )
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HELLO!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {
        super.onMessageReceived( messageEvent );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the two:

1. Try setting a "setResultCallback" when you send a message and check whether you receive a response.
2. You could use Data API since Data API provides 100% guarantee whereas Message API is dropped at times. Also, Data API compares the previous and current data and sends only if at least one of the data is changed.

You could use Data API and send the data as

```
PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(*WEAR_ID*);
putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("duration", duration);
putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("type", type);
putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("name", name); 
putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("Starting Time", startingTime);
putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putBoolean("Stop", false);
```